# Scheduled reminders based on a custom field on an activity

Tags: custom-fields, activities, scheduled-reminders

I know that in CiviCRM 4.6, the ability to send scheduled reminders to people based on a custom field (e.g. marriage date) was added.  However, I'm unsure if it's possible to send a scheduled reminder based on the custom field of an ACTIVITY.  I couldn't figure out how, if so.

The use case is to have a custom activity field labeled, "Remind me on X date", which is similar to functionality present in Raiser's Edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the custom date field feature is only for dates on the contact record, not activities. Doing activities would take a change in core--it would be comparable to the work to do the contact date fields. It would be a great feature, though!